# How do I write numerals in a string literal?

Tags: delphi

My following Delphi code is throwing a compiler error: incompatible type: string and integer in line

```
SQL.Text := 'Select ColumnA from TableA where ColumnA NOT IN ('+ 3 + ',' + 4 +')';
```

How do I put the numbers in the SQL statement?

Comment: You should use parameters. Do NOT concatenate a SQL string. What if the numbers are floating points, and someone is using comma as decimal separator, but your SQL server uses a decimal dot. Or what if the parameters are strings, and the user can fill the variable with a SQL injection attempt?

Comment: And the reverse transformation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21229162 - for the SO inter-connectivity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line should look like this:

`SQL.Text := 'Select ColumnA from TableA where ColumnA NOT IN (3,4)';`

Comment: What if I have var firstVal, secondVal : integer; firstVal := 3; secondVal := 4 and I have to use these variables in the query

Comment: @NareshKumar `SQL.Text := 'Select ColumnA from TableA where ColumnA NOT IN ('+ IntToStr(firstVal) + ',' + IntToStr(secondVal) +')';`

Comment: Yes, it does work, thanks. Conclusion is that you have to use string in SQL.Text statement.

Answer (score 7):

When writing these sort of statements (and parameters are not in scope),  try to use the Format function:

```
SQL.Text := Format('Select ColumnA from TableA where ColumnA NOT IN (%d,%d)',
                  [Firstval, SecondVal]);
```

One big advantage writing the query this way is that you keep the SQL statement readable (like when you use parameters).