# Change from string to integer

Tags: delphi

EveryOne I need some esay way to change from integer and string in delphi 7

```
var 
Str:String;
Int:Integer;
// Here what i need to do
Str:='123';
Int:=Str.AsInteger
// or use this
Int:=123;
Str=Int.AsString;
```

Comment: For unsafe casting use `StrToInt` function, for safe casting e.g. `TryStrToInt`.

Comment: To add to  TLama - there is also `StrToIntDef`

Comment: And the reverse transformation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14317264 - for the SO inter-connectivity

Answer (score 9):

The easiest way is to use these two methods:

```
IntVal := StrToInt(StrVal);    // will throw EConvertError if not an integer
StrVal := IntToStr(IntVal);    // will always work
```

You can also use the more fault-tolerant `TryStrToInt` (far better than catching `EConvertError`):

```
if not TryStrToInt(StrVal, IntVal) then
  begin
  // error handling
  end;
```

If you want to resort to a default value instead of handling errors explictly you can use:

```
IntVal := StrToIntDef(StrVal, 42);    // will return 42 if StrVal cannot be converted
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're using a recent version of Delphi, in addition to the previous answers, you can alternatively use a pseudo-OOP syntax as you wanted to originally - the naming convention is just ToXXX not AsXXX:

```
Int := Str.ToInteger
Str := Int.ToString;
```

The Integer helper also adds Parse and TryParse methods:

```
Int := Integer.Parse(Str);
if Integer.TryParse(Str, Int) then //...
```

Comment: Why do you say "pseudo" here? It looks pretty plain OOP syntax to me.

Comment: I meant to the extent strings and integers remain not objects in any proper OOP sense (there's no inheritance etc.)

Comment: I would not say that inheritance is needed for OOP. Consider a value type to be a sealed class.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: There wouldn't have been any `Create` to either `Str` or `Int`, though. Implicit instantiation? Well, whatever. :)

Comment: @AndriyM `std::string str;`

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Sorry, I'm not familiar with that syntax in Delphi (if that's Delphi now), but `Str.ToInteger` would work if `Str` was declared simply as `var Str: string;` without any explicit creation/instantiation before the `ToInteger` call. That's what I meant by "implicit instantiation". Anyway, so far those are record helpers but perhaps the new syntax in general is indeed paving the way to making Delphi (or some branch of it) a true OO language, like Smalltalk or something, where everything is an object.

Comment: @AndriyM - personally I hope not, as there are far more pressing things for them to do. That said, I like (and use for XE5 projects) the method syntax, and find the way it's been implemented perfectly satisfactory (I see no real benefit of making `string` descend from `TObject`).

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
StrToInt(s)
```

and

```
IntToStr(i)
```

functions.

Comment: thank you but i dont need as that ...!
look this exsample.

`type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject); 
  end;


 Integer = class
    FValue: System.Integer;
    function ToString: string;
    public
      property Value: System.Integer read FValue write FValue;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

 
function Integer.ToString: string;
begin
  Str(FValue, Result);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
op:integer;
begin
  op.Value:=45;
  Edit1.Text:=op.ToString;
end;

end.`